# MySQL on Amazon?

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2

I'd like to have 20 different `Amazon EC2` instances that read and write from the same shared location. Is it at all possible?

Also, is it possible to have an instance of `MySQL` that will be accessible from all 20 `Amazon EC2` instances?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use [Amazon's RDS](http://aws.amazon.com/rds/) which offers a managed MySql service which all your instances could access. Otherwise yes of course it is possible to have a single MySql instance running which all your other instances can access in which case you will need to configure MySql to allow remote connections and open the EC2 port (3306 by default) on the database server.

Comment: thank you. What is the difference between `RDS` and just setup my 'own' `MySQL` instance?

Comment: Well RDS offers the convenience of not having to worry about traffic load and backups etc. but for an additional cost (you can see the pricing details on that page). Running your own mysql means you can have a finer control over the system but then you have extra work to ensure reliability and redunancy etc.

Answer (score 2):

The whole idea of a database server is to provide a **shared** data repository. If you can get to your single MySQL instance over the network, you shouldn't have a problem.